# Создание туннелей на linux

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

У меня есть виртульная машина, в которй установлена еще одна виртуалка (обе на линукс), я хочу изнутри второй виртуалки пингануть первую. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать, если в данном случае создание сетвого моста невозможно? Как создать туннель?

Comment: а добавить их в одну подсеть?

Comment: Ага, сетевой мост чем не устроил?